# I want to upload custom Helm charts on IBM Cloud Private internal repository, but I am not able to do so

Tags: repository, local, kubernetes-helm, ibm-cloud-private

I followed [this official ICP link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSBS6K_2.1.0/app_center/add_package.html), but I not able to get final command that uploads charts to ICP working (command:bx pr load-helm-chart --archive  [--clustername ]).

Here is my output:
[CLI output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4s8yx.png)

We got error in helmrepo pod.

[Logs in helmrepo pod are here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Nqie.png).

Output of "docker  logs -f" for helmrepo here:
[docker  logs -f](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpoFn.png)

Answer (score 0):

I would check your helm-api and helm-repo pods:

```
kubectl get pods -n kube-system | grep helm
helm-api-9c7f7667d-6x2pw                                  1/1       Running   0          28d
helmrepo-689487f674-ls6zp                                 1/1       Running   0          28d
```

Check all the pods, auth pods or icp-ds pod being flakey can cause an issue as well. Replace any pod thats not healthy:

```
kubectl get pod PODNAME -n NAMESPACE -o yaml | kubectl replace --force -f -
```

Comment: I have edited the question and posted helmrepo pod logs. Please see if it helps

Comment: So now that we see the catalog repo seems to return OK but the API call to PUT your chart in the catalog pukes with a 404.... 

What is the output of 

kubectl get pods -n kube-system

?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely check the pod health, like jfos suggested. If all of the pods are healthy, can you post the logs for the helm repo pod?

From the master node: 
`docker ps | grep helmrepo`

The response should look something like this:

`test-machine:~# docker ps | grep repo
b5614d015d5b        341e5add26f5                                      "npm start"               About an hour ago   Up About an hour                        k8s_helm-repo_helm-repo-5d46fd5fcc-pmpqm_kube-system_5fae427b-3d1b-11e8-91f8-00163e01b44f_0`

Where the pod_id is `b5614d015d5b`.

Then, to view logs: `docker logs pod_id -f`

In this example, it would be `docker logs b5614d015d5b -f`

Look for the 404 response and post the surrounding logs.

Comment: you are right. i have error in helmrepo pod. I have edited question and added image of logs. Please see if it helps. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you have http/https proxy set on the host to run 'bx pr load-helm-chart' command? If yes, please unset the proxy to try, thanks.